# Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaling and Resource Quota

Tags: kubernetes, resources, quota, hpa, horizontalpodautoscaler

Does the resource quota take into account the pods created by the HPA (Horizontal pod autoscaler) ?

If the new created pods have Resquests and Limits superior to the Quota are they evicted?

Regards

Comment: Could you please give more details about your issue? Some examples will be welcome.

Comment: For example a namespace with a quota of 1cpu and 2Go Ram. If i have a pod in that namespace with a request of 1 cpu and 2Go ram that means i can't add more pods. But if i activate the autoscaling (HPA) hat means more pods can be added automatically by the HPA. My question: the pods can be added by the HPA or not?

Answer (score 1):

When The HPA is triggered new pods are scheduled to be created while resources allocation if they exceed the any quota they will get 403 FORBIDDEN with a message explaining the constraint that would have been violated from the api server and wont be scheduled.